# Firebase user registration with username atomicity

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have created a login system for Firebase. The user can authenticate with a username or password. This is possible by creating a table in the firebase database that links usernames and emails.

The problem is that, when the user is registering, he can do anything between the "createUserWithEmailAndPassword()" call to firebase and its completion handler where i add the user to the database. For example: going back to the previous activity, pausing the app with onpause, rotating the screen, ...
if the user is doing these things, it would be possible that the user is registered but not written to the database

How can i make sure this transaction is all or nothing? I thought about using an intentservice that stops itself when done, but is this really the way to go ?

```
private void register(final String email,final String username,final String password)
{
   mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>()
   {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task)
        {
            Log.d("FIREBASE Register", "createUserWithEmail:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());
            showProgress(false);

            if(task.isSuccessful())
            {
                Resources res = getResources();
                SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(res.getString(R.string.package_name), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                editor.putString("email",     email);
                editor.putString("password", password);
                editor.commit();


                // Write new user
                FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                writeNewUser(user.getUid(), username, email);

                // Send verification email
                sendVerificationEmail();

                // Sign out the user, to block the loginActivity from logging in the user (the email isn't verified)
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: The task is handled on the background by firebase, you dont have to do anything

Comment: No, not when you need an extra call to firebase to store   the username

Comment: Have you tried?

Comment: Yes, a firebase transaction is all or nothing, but i'm doing 2 transactions here. If i put the app in the background, the oncomplete will not be executed and my database will be inconsistent

Comment: My bad, i would have tought that when the on complete another async task would be called.

Comment: Just checked, everything is handled on the background, both are async tasks

Comment: Yes but this doesn't have anything to do with this... the second asynctask (in the writeUser method) isn't executed if the app is paused or terminated right after createUserWithEmailAndPassword

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by using a service, but after longer research i found that delegating the mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword method to a HandlerThread would also be a great solution

source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=adPLIAnx9og&t=78s
(the example with the camera.open and onpreview callback)

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is the best approach since if the user leaves the app it would force him to do everything again

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    final FirebaseAuth mAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    final FirebaseUser user=mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    final DatabaseReference mdatabase=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("USERS NODE").child(user.getUid());
    mdatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(dataSnapshot==null){
                //DATA HAS NOT BEEN SUMBITED
                if(user!=null){

                    user.delete()
                            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                                    }
                                }
                            });
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });



}
```

Comment: i don't think this is a solution. The email of the user would be registered, and the username/email table in the firebase would be empty. Things would still be inconsistent. This code is just logging out the user if the user leaves the activity. But this brought me on an idea: i could use the ondestroy to remove the user if the oncomplete isn't called

Comment: Just made an edit, with this one it would not be inconsistent

Comment: This would be better indeed. I will check it out later. Thanks

Comment: Tried it out, or at least something like this, it lead to a few errors. So i ended up writing a bound service that kills itself when done, this works

Comment: Awesome, if it helped you could consider accepting my answer